# Disposição de tags em uma div, padding e magin

Tags: div, css-padding, floating

Bom, meu professor pediu para "clonar" o site do facebook como exercício para aplicar o que foi aprendido com html e css durante a aula. Porém, não consigo deixar os dois labels "senha" e "email" em cima dos dois input text correspondentes, ao utilizar margin left ele arrasta o resto dos inputs para o mesmo lado.

Aqui está o código fonte:

```css
*{
margin:0px;
  
}

#divSuperior{
 
 height:82px;
 width:100%;
 background-color:#3b5998;
 z_index:1;

}
#divSuperior h1{

 float:left;
 padding-left:190px;
 padding-top:26px;
 font-size: 36px;
 font-family: arial;
}

#divSuperior h1 a{

 text-decoration: none;
 color: white;
}

#Email{ 

 float:right;
 border:1px solid black;
 height:22px;
 width: 150px;
 margin-top:32px;
 margin-right:12px;
}
#Senha{

 float:right;
 border:1px solid black;
 height:22px;
 width: 150px;
 margin-top:32px;
 margin-right:75px;
}

#labEmail{

 float:right;
 color:white;
 font-family: arial;
 font-size:12px;
 cursor:pointer;
 margin-top:10px;

}

#labSenha{

 float:right; 
 color:white;
 font-family: arial;
 font-size:12px;
 cursor:pointer;
}

#botaoEntrar{

 float:right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Facebook - entre ou cadastre-se</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Facebook.css">
</head>
<body>

<div id = "divSuperior">
 <h1><a href = "www.facebook.com.br"><b>Facebook</b></a></h1>

 <button type="button" id = "botaoEntrar">Entrar</button> 
 <label for = "Senha" id = "labSenha">Senha</label>
 <label for = "Email" id = "labEmail">Email ou telefone</label>
 <input type="text" id = "Senha">
 <input type="text" id = "Email"/>  
 
</div>
<div id = "divEsquerda"></div>
<div id = "divDireita"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Boas tenta colocar os campos dentro de um form e os nomes dos campos como `Email` e `password` mete em `span` para poderes melhor usar no css, se não funcionar faz uma div especifica para isso com `width:100%` mexes no `float: left;` e vais ajustando. Depois depende de como está o resto do código e as divs .